# How to download excel template will display with only header in Laravel Excel 3.1?

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, laravel-6, laravel-excel

Good Day guys,.. I need to download a excel template only show with headers,..

I have good and working function code in laravel-excel version 2 of my problem,. but in version 3.1 i dont know how to code it.

this is my code in version 2;

```
public function downloadCoursesTemplate()
{
    $columns = array(
        'Course Code',
        'Course Description',
        'Status'
    );

    return Excel::download('Courses', function ($excel) use ($columns) {
        $excel->sheet('Courses', function ($sheet) use ($columns) {
            $sheet->fromArray($columns);
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

this is the output:

[image]

I want that on laravel-excel version 3.1

There have documentation in new versions but i could not find it to solve my issue.

Is anyone can help me? thanks. sorry for my English grammar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation should be pretty clear, it even has a quick start guide [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/)

But here is what you can do:

Generate the export class

```
php artisan make:export CoursesTemplateExport
```

Change the class to the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class CoursesTemplateExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function array(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Course Code',
            'Course Description',
            'Status'
        ];
    }
}
```

We can implement the `FromArray` interface so we can just return an empty array since we don't have any data, and we can implement the `WithHeadings` interface to declare the headings the export should have.

In your Controller:

```
use App\Exports\CoursesTemplateExport;

public function downloadCoursesTemplate()
{
    return Excel::download(new CoursesTemplateExport(), 'Courses.xlsx');
}
```

This will result in the following excel:

[image]

Comment: sana all @AbingPj

Comment: can we make this column names not editable?